# (feature discontinued) Google Hangouts phone app: How to start a group SMS where one of the recipients is a Hangouts user?

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm actually answering my own question here, and the purpose for this is because the question hasn't been clearly stated before.

Imagine the following scenario:

- I have a friend named Joe who uses Google Hangouts on his cell phone
- I have a friend named Mary who uses a cell phone, but does not have
  Google Hangouts

I would like to send a group message to both of them.  I know that Joe can receive SMS or Hangouts, but Mary only has the capability to send/receive SMS/MMS.  How can I ensure my message is compatible for Mary?

Comment: I'm assuming this is relevant to the app (iOS or Android?)  I came looking for how to do on PC and doesn't seem to match up.  Please clarify title for future searchers.

Comment: As of May 22, 2017, Google Hangouts no longer supports SMS messaging.  I have adjusted the title to reflect this.

Comment: not sure why you say that, I'm still actively using it for sms both on my Android and on my PC device.  In the end I ended up starting the group text on my device in Hangouts as I never quite got it on the pc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two different ways:

**Method 1:**

1. In Hangouts, tap the + button
2. Tap "New SMS"
3. Find Mary and tap on her entry.  The combination of step 2 and 3 will solidify the message as an SMS.  If you select Joe (our Hangouts contact) first, it may convert to a Hangouts message, so it is important to start with your SMS contact first!
4. Find Joe and tap on his entry
5. Tap the green arrow to continue.  In my case, I have two numbers I can send from (my carrier number or a Google Voice Number), so I would select my desired number.

**Method 2:**

1. In Hangouts, send a message to Mary
2. While staying in Mary's conversation, tap the "three dots" button in the upper right
3. Tap "New Group MMS"
4. Find Joe and tap on his entry
5. Tap the green arrow to continue.  In my case, I have two numbers I can send from (my carrier number or a Google Voice Number), so I would select my desired number.

**Testing**

In either situation, you can test if you were successful by tapping the "three dots" button in the upper right of your group message.

- If the dropdown has an option for "Delete", then you are in a group SMS/MMS
- If the dropdown has an option for "Leave", then you are in a hangout

*Tested on Hangouts version 10.0*